# Ruby -- array of hashes, getting unique values

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, hash, functional-programming

I have the following array of hashes:

```
persons = [
  {name: 'Mark', age: 28},
  {name: 'John', age: 45},
  {name: 'Sam', age: 34},
  {name: 'John', age: 34}
]
```

I want to get an array of unique values for the key `name`. In this case it should be `['Mark', 'John', 'Sam']`.

Here is my solution:

```
names = []

persons.each do |person|
  names << person[:name] unless names.include? person[:name]
end
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine `map` and `uniq`:

```
persons = [
  {name: 'Mark', age: 28},
  {name: 'John', age: 45},
  {name: 'Sam', age: 34},
  {name: 'John', age: 34}
]

persons.map { |p| p[:name] }.uniq #=> ["Mark", "John", "Sam"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use `Set` here:

```
require 'set'
persons.each_with_object(Set.new) { |person, set| set << person[:name] }.to_a
#=> ["Mark", "John", "Sam"]
```

Or by using hash:

```
persons.group_by { |p| p[:name] }.keys
#=> ["Mark", "John", "Sam"]
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the converting the set to an array will provide the desired order of the names. You could use a hash, however.

Comment: or `persons.collect{|p| p[:name]}.to_set.to_a`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, there is nothing in question about order :) However, here is an alternative solution with hash too.